# Converting MySQL to H2

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, h2

I’m working on a project following this code : 
Link to download of code: https://bitbucket.org/vrto/spring-tutorial/get/a66534cc7033.zip

Now what I really want, instead of MySQL, is to have an embedded database running HSQL or H2. So I’ve working on my own project trying to implement such a system.

In the tutorial code, he creates a database. And then h2 + hibernates creates the future tables for him – so it would be create if I could do this without having to have an sql schema or anything to set it up. 
 So I’ve gotten rid of mySql maven dependencies and am working on replacing the persistence-beans.xml
Now I have to replace my dataSource with a relevant h2 or hsql version.
So this is what I’ve gotten.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name ="driverClassName" value = "org.h2.driver"/>
    <property name = "url" value ="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
    <property name = "username" value = "sa" />
    <property name = "password" value = "" /> 
</bean>

// I also tried this (but again, having a schema with his code is tricky I’ve found

<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

But it fails upon running HibernateConfigurationTest.Java (and in extension – all the others)
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've managed to get this test work with my schema

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/persistence-beans.xml")
public class HibernateConfigurationTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Test
    public void testHibernateConfiguration() {
        // Spring IOC container instantiated and prepared sessionFactory
        assertNotNull (sessionFactory); 
    }

}
```

the rest tests are in this link : http://vrtoonjava.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/part-3-dao-and-service-layer/

Comment: did you try jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;

Comment: this does not work either @SparkOn

Comment: It wolud be helpful if you show your test class as many functionalities are different in mysql from H2

Comment: Did you change the hibernate dialect?

Comment: whats that and where is that ? @MartinFrey

Comment: Search your config for a property `hibernate.dialect `. You will need to change this from `MySQLDialect` to `H2Dialect`. Some examples: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_configuration.htm

Comment: @Neyon. Can you post your hibernate configuration?